# ¿Cómo puedo agregar dinámicamente un componente a una GUI en JAVA?

Tags: java, java-swing, interfaz-gráfica

Estoy aquí nuevamente para solucionar un dolor de cabeza que no logro comprender.

**NOTA**: Estoy usando Swing, un paquete construido encima de la AWT de Java.

Se que mi error principal es el no comprender como funcionan bien las GUI en Java. Así que aquí mi ejemplo de programación para entender.

Yo quiero agregar, cada vez que se presiona un botón en pantalla, una `JTextField` en el `Content Pane` de mi GUI. Aquí mi código:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        javax.swing.JPanel panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                panel.add(new JTextField());
                FORM.add(panel);                                                     
                FORM.validate();
                FORM.repaint();
                
            }
        });
```

Éste código es el `eventListener` de el mismo botón (*Add Labels* <- ver imágen). El objeto **FORM** es una referencia al formulario GUI del que estoy hablando.

Yo quiero que los campos de texto se muestren en columnas hacia abajo de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**¿Cómo puedo lograr esto? ¿Cuál es mi error?**

**NOTA 2:** No sé como utilizar **Layouts** (y eso que he leído la documentación de Oracle, no la comprendo).

**NOTA 3:** Utilizo el creador gráfico de Swing. El que ya viene integrado con NetBeans IDE.

**NOTA 4:** Al parecer funciona creando otro layout para **FORM**. Pero los componentes no se muestran de la forma que yo quiero. Además, quiero mantener el diseño (horrible) de la GUI que se muestra en imagen.

**PROGRESO 1:** He intentado hacer mi propio layout para el panel pero no he logrado mucho progreso. No queda donde quiero y cuando genero mas campos de texto, se superponen.
Desde ya muchísimas gracias.

> Este es un fragmento del método main de la clase `FormAutocompleteGUI2`

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            var form = new FormAutocompleteGUI2();
            form.setVisible(true);
            form.initActionHandlers(form);
            form.setTitle("Form autocomplete algorithm | Pespepan Pinpos");
        });
```

> Este es el código del método `initActionHandlers()`

```
public void initActionHandlers(FormAutocompleteGUI2 form) {
        addQuesBtn.addActionListener(new addQuestionActionHandler(this));
        exitBtn.addActionListener(event -> {
            System.exit(0);
        });
    }
```

> Este es el código en la clase `addQuestionActionHandler`

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        javax.swing.JPanel panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                panel.add(new JTextField());
                FORM.add(panel);                                                     
                FORM.validate();
                FORM.repaint();
                
            }
        });
```

Comment: Tal vez para obtener más ayuda con tu pregunta, sería bueno que incluyas más acerca de tu **Form**, para que a las personas les sea más fácil reproducir tu problema

Comment: @EduardoJiménez claro! Ya mismo la agrego

Comment: @EduardoJiménez Agregado! Sucede que el resto es autogenerado por el mismo IDE.

Comment: Si no usas layout posiciona cada campo de texto con su método `setBounds()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si aún no entiendes mucho de GUI, supongo que el layout que estás utilizando es el absolute, que te permite colocar las cosas donde te dé la gana pero luego no es responsivo... Vamos a recrear lo que tienes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ves, he agregado un panel debajo, ahí es donde agregaremos los componentes. Yo estoy utilizando WindowBuilder para crear todo de manera gráfica, si tú no lo tienes, te recomiendo instalarlo (en netbeans viene por defecto, en eclipse se descarga en Market). Ahora, la clave para que se creen uno debajo de otro, es poner BoxLayout vertical a ese nuevo panel:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setBounds(46, 209, 221, 254);
contentPane.add(panel);
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
```

Ya simplemente nos queda poner un listener al botón para que cada vez que le llame, agrege un componente nuevo:

```
btnAgregar.addActionListener(e -> {
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Texto que quieras");
    panel.add(label);
    panel.validate();
});
```

Espero que se entienda,

Un saludo

Comment: Hola! Agradezco muchísimo tu respuesta. En cuanto llegue a mi domicilio lo pondré a prueba y te daré mis resultados! Gracias por nutrirme de conocimiento.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que la respuesta es muy sencilla.

Deberías llamar `repaint()` y `revalidate()` después de agregar tu componente a tu Panel para poder lograr visualizar los cambios en tiempo de ejecución.